# Why is Java Robot Keypres function not working for Big Sur?

Tags: java, macos-big-sur, awtrobot

I am using MacBook Pro M1 Big Sur. I am using Eclipse to make a java program that can type the letter "A".

My program is

```
package code;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot player = new Robot();
        
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
            player.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);


    }

}
```

However, whenever I run this code, the java app opens but nothing else happens (it doesn't press the letter A). I have already enabled accessibly permissions to Eclipse so I'm not sure why it's happening. Please help.

Comment: Is the app you're trying to interact with full screen?

Comment: Yeah, it is trying to interact with the full screen.